# What is the name of this view?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm want to use [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar) in my project. In the documentation is states that the [this view](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar/master/Screens/example.png) isn't provided. Does anyone know the name of this view? I want to use the timeline view along with calendar view. Thank you!

[image: This is the view I want to use]

Comment: It's called *the part that you write yourself.*

Comment: Yes I know that, nevertheless it is a third party view. [Used in this app](http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/28/b8/0e/28b80e61-911b-bae5-5772-0739a6a0ae1b/screen322x572.jpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an example the developer did put.

If you are searching a day timeline control i recommend you

[Tapku Calendar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tapku-calendar)

The calendar is also available via Cocoapods.

By my experience, i recommend you to make a stack of events with a UITableView, instead of a day timeline from 00:00
to 23:00, for example

Instead of

00:00 -

01:00 - Date with Tiffany

02:00 -

03:00 - Go home

You can do:

01:15 - Date with Tiffany (Pic Here)

03:20 - Go Home (Map Link)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both!